# Design Question: Which is better? Many Databases or Many Collections?

Tags: arangodb

I've been using arangodb community version for sometime and soon will be starting a new commercial project soon. As i am pondering and working on the system and database designs, I'm stuck on this performance question. Should I create one database per customer or group them in large collections instead?

To give abit of background, the project objective is have a bot that execute tasks given or set by the users. My concern is where each user's bot has to constantly read the users' collection data and execute or followup tasks every few seconds, thus the great attention on designing for performance and speed. 
Furthermore, the deployment will be on cloud servers hence the needs for gauging the memory usage, CPU and disk space. Clustering is not required as each user entity is totally separated and I will do load balancing by directing a pool of users to their dedicated cloud server.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Foxx instances can only access a single database, does Foxx come into consideration? I'm assuming it's multi-tennant, how many tennants are you expecting to have on a single 'installation' or 'instance' of your infrastructure?

I think the true answer to the problem will be found by you testing some scenarios, talking with your security people/auditors, understanding customer sensitivity to using multitennant instances, and many other questions like that.

Comment: Look my advice is to start with the simplest database possible that meets your requirements. Do not over engineer at this point because you cannot possibly know where all your bottlenecks will be at this early stage. Starting with a single DB (as long as it meets your needs) gives you multiple growth options. You can start with one, then you can shard tables as needed, and then if you have a customer big enough, you can always break it into its own DB.